# Flash Object Positioning Issues

Tags: css, flash

New to development.  Two position-related issues with the same Flash object:

1) After experimentation/research I was able to position my Flash element with CSS.  However I have not found a way to get it to properly reposition when the browser window is resized, as the other page elements do.  It will slide vertically, but stays horizontally fixed.

2) The position is now proper in Firefox, Safari and Chrome.  But IE applies excessive left-justification and changes the object size.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Address: www.mconchicago.com

Code:

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    #container {
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    top:110px;
    left:177px;
    margin: 0 auto;
 }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">

<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" 


codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/
cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0" 

width="100%" height="100%"

style="margin: 0px 0 0px 0px"

width="590" height="300" 
id="mymoviename"> 

<param name="movie"  

value="banner_creator.swf" /> 

<param name="quality" value="high" /> 

<param name=”wmode” value=”transparent” />

<param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" /> 

<embed src="banner_creator.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#ffffff"

width="590" height="180" 

name="mymoviename" align="" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 

pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"> 


</embed> 

</object>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Not really an answer, but can you make sure in `#container` you set `padding: 0;`.  IE is known for double-padding.

Comment: Sometime after this string of events took place the entire site was relaunched.  I have archived the old files.  If you want to see the results of this Flash advice, for the time-being at least, you can view http://www.mconchicago.com/MCON/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have quite a mess in your code I must admit.

I believe it's possible to fix it though :-)

first move the whole `div id='container'` into 'wrapsky' (before `<div class="imagesky">`)

then apply the style:

```
.wrapsky {
    height: 180px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    width: 998px;
}
```

and

```
#container {
    float: left;
    height: 200px;  
    width: 590px;
}
```

it's not ideal but it should do for now :-)

Comment: My friend, you are the man.  That was enough to get it together.  I'm sure the entire site's code must look like a mess as I learn by trying things.  Once everything is working right I plan to go back and remove the stuff that doesn't matter.  Thank you very much and have a good night.